# Android Studio/Firestore: Chance Color of TextView in RecyclerView by Firestore Boolean?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, textview

Inside my Firestore Cloud-Storage I got this Boolean-field inside Products/Productid/: **"isOffer"**.

I want to change the color of the TextView-String "mPrice" inside my RecyclerView ProductItems, regarding if "isOffer" is true or false, but I have no Idea how to handle that.

Method createRecycler():

```
 public void createRecycler(){
    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.product_selection_list);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    Query query = current_productRef.whereEqualTo("isAvailable", true);
    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<product_selection_Item> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<product_selection_Item>()
            .setQuery(query, product_selection_Item.class)
            .build();
    mAdapter = new product_selection_Adapter(options);

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new product_selection_Adapter.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void OnItemClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position) {
            String id = documentSnapshot.getId();
            Intent intent = new Intent(product_selection.this, product_fill.class);
            intent.putExtra("Product_ID", id);

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

My Adapter for the Recycler is pretty basic:

```
public class product_selection_Adapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<product_selection_Item, product_selection_Adapter.product_selection_ViewHolder> {
private OnItemClickListener mListener;

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void OnItemClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position);
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}


public class product_selection_ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView mProductname;
    public TextView mFat_Value;
    public TextView mPrice;

    public product_selection_ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
        super(itemView);
        mProductname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_selection_name);
        mFat_Value = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_selection_fat);
        mPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_selection_price);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(listener != null) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                        listener.OnItemClick(getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position), position);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

public product_selection_Adapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<product_selection_Item> options) {
    super(options);
}


@NonNull
@Override
public product_selection_ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.product_selection_item, parent, false);
    product_selection_ViewHolder ViewHolder = new product_selection_ViewHolder(v, mListener);
    return ViewHolder;
}

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull product_selection_ViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull product_selection_Item model) {

    holder.mProductname.setText(model.getmProductname());
    holder.mFat_Value.setText(String.valueOf(model.getmFat_Value() + "% Fett"));
    holder.mPrice.setText(String.valueOf(model.getmPrice().get(0) + " €"));
}
```

}

Can you help me out here?

Thank you in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

I needed to create a new Attribute inside my **Product_Selection_Item - Class** "isOffer" with the getter "getisOffer".

After that, inside the Adapter I simply created a new boolean variable "isOffer" which gets the value of the current bool. Just like:

```
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull product_selection_ViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull product_selection_Item model) {

    holder.mProductname.setText(model.getmProductname());
    holder.mFat_Value.setText(String.valueOf(model.getmFat_Value() + "% Fett"));
    holder.mPrice.setText(String.valueOf(model.getmPrice().get(0) + " €"));
    holder.isOffer = model.getisOffer();
    if(holder.isOffer){
        holder.mPrice.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#D90000"));
    }
    else{
        holder.mPrice.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    }
}
```

Don't know, if that's the best solution, but it worked for me! :)

**Edit:**

This only works like that, because I'm using the **FirestoreUI** with the **FirestoreRecyclerAdapter**.

Here, every getter with the Attribute of the Product_Selection_Item which has the same name inside the Firestore Storage, will be connected automatically to Firestore.

That's why I simply can do *"holder.isOffer = model.getisOffer();"*